# OSX status bar menu occasionally not dismising other status bar menus

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, user-interface, statusbar

So I have a status bar app that launches a small popover in the form of an NSPanel that has transient behaviour. However occasionally if I open say the Dropbox popover and then open my apps popover the dropbox menu will not disappear until I click a button in my popover. Which is strange because it only happens sometimes, and I am using `[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];` when opening the popover. It works with Skypes drop down menu as well as a host of other status bar applications. There are a couple that won't dismiss when I open mine until I make an interaction in my popover. Is there a way to set focus to that button or something in the panel that might help force the other menus to close all the time?